# Dismiss Permission Request Dialog on Marshmallow using back button

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-6.0-marshmallow

In my App, I am verifying required permissions for Marshmallow devices, in accordance to google guidelines.
When the permission is required, I am using the request permissions method for that:

`mActivity.requestPermissions(permissionsList, MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST)`, which displays dialogs similar to the dialog below:

[image: Permission request]

While this dialog is displayed, if the user presses the back button, I would like the dialog to be dismissed. Currently, pushing the back button has no effect.

Is there a way to dismiss those dialogs using the back button?

Comment: I doubt it, as that's not your dialog. It's a system-supplied dialog-themed activity, and they apparently decided against having BACK do anything, for some screwball reason.

Comment: @CommonsWare Same thing I thought. I was wondering if someone found a workaround so every dialog in the app would have the same behavior.

Comment: @brWHigino Did you get the solution?.I want to dismiss the permission dialog in my application.

Answer (score 0):

You know what, I believe it's a bug in AOSP. It should ignore Back button for no reason.

Reported an issue to bugtracker:
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=231017&thanks=231017&ts=1482770758